# List rows not centered

Tags: swiftui

I am displaying some rows in a list (actually, 2 parallel lists in the example posted here), from a custom row view labeled `EventRow`.
In order to avoid bad UI on larger devices like an iPad, I limited the width of the EventRow to 200.
How could I get the EventRows to be centered in my lists on larger devices ?
I tried applying a `.center` alignment to the EventRows in the ForEach methods of my lists, tried doing the same on the lists as well, but nothing seems to work.

As an alternate solution, is there a way to set a MAX Spacer width ? I know you can set a minLength, but not a MAX it seems...

Here's a screenshot on the iPad Pro 11 sim :

[image]

The code for my EventRow file is as follows :

```
import SwiftUI

struct EventRow: View {

    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            HStack {
                Text("Text one")
                Spacer()
                Text("Text two")
            }
            HStack {
                Spacer()
                Image(systemName: "flame")
                    .font(.body)
                Spacer()
            } // END of second HStack
                .padding(.top, -14)
        } //END of Vstack
        .frame(maxWidth: 200) // To limit width on larger devices
        .listRowBackground(LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [Color.white, Color.blue]), startPoint: .top, endPoint: .bottom))
    }
}

struct EventRow_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
       EventRow().previewLayout(.fixed(width: 300, height: 60))

    }
}
```

And my ContentView :

```
struct ContentView: View {

    struct listsSetup: ViewModifier {
      func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        return content
        .frame(maxHeight: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height/3)
        .overlay(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10).stroke(Color.blue, lineWidth: 1))
            .padding([.top, .bottom])
        }
    }
    @State private var selected : Int = 0

    var body: some View {

        VStack {
                HStack {
                    VStack { // 1 list Vstack
                        VStack {
                        Text("List 1")
                            .padding(.top)
                        List {
                            EventRow()
                            EventRow()
                        } // END of 1st List
                        }
                            .modifier(listsSetup())
                    } // END of 1st list VStack

                    VStack { // 2nd Vstack
                        VStack {
                        Text("List 2")
                            .padding(.top)
                        List {
                            EventRow()
                            EventRow()
                        } // END of Landings List
                        }
                        .modifier(listsSetup())
                    } // End of 2nd List VStack
                } // End of 1st & 2nd lists HStack
                    .padding(.top)
                Spacer()


            Picker("", selection: $selected){
                Text("0").tag(0)
                Text("1").tag(1)
            }.pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())

            Text("\(selected)")
        } // END of VStack
    } // END of body

}
```

Again, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just embed it in one more container, like below (tested with Xcode 11.4)

[image: demo]

```
    VStack {
        VStack{
            HStack {
                Text("Text one")
                Spacer()
                Text("Text two")
            }
            HStack {
                Spacer()
                Image(systemName: "flame")
                    .font(.body)
                Spacer()
            } // END of second HStack
                .padding(.top, -14)
        } //END of Vstack
        .frame(maxWidth: 200) // To limit width on larger devices
    }.frame(maxWidth: .infinity)   // << here !!
```